# Adding blog image using looping in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf in my spring boot blog project, I am getting all data from database except blog images. I don't want to store images in database, instead want to add them to images folder and get it from there. Is there anyway to get images from images folder and loop it for each post instead of adding manually.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                <div class="x_panel" th:each="post : ${posts}">
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <div class="card mt-4" >
                            <img style="width: 100%" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x400" alt="">
                            <h3 class="card-title" th:text="${post.title}">Product Name</h3>
                            <div class="card-body" th:text="${post.body}">
                            <p class="card-text" th:text="${post.date}"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Please edit the question and include the text (formatted) instead.

Comment: Suggestion: Store each image name (and location, if needed) as another piece of data in your `post` entity: `post.image` or something like that. Format your image URL using the Thymeleaf [link url](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls) syntax.

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames, I guess this is the best option, will go for it. Thank you,